# Are there ways to debug conditions of process builder?

Tags: process-builder

Some of my actions, in process builder, aren't firing and i'm trying to figure out where it's choking up.

I'm not sure which process has fired based on the conditions i've set.

Does anyone know if it's possible to debug process builder?

Answer (score 5):

After cursory research, it seems there are several ways to debug process builder:

**Debug Log:**

Since process builder is built with workflow and is another layer on top it can be debugged via debug logs:

This knowledgebase article has information regarding debugging workflow: [Debugging workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Process-Rules-and-Workflow-Rules&language=en_US)

In the debug log look for the workflow rule that is being triggered.

**Apex Class:**
This particular is cheap and less useful
Create an apex class that fires a simple System.debug call. Be sure to add the @invocablemethod annotation so process builder will pick it up.